# Need help filling datagrid from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, datagridview

I have made a table in mysql with attributes Product code,Quantity,company,price. And I have created a datagridview in vb 2012 and I want to take input from the form and then display the results in a datagridview. I also want to display price from the table I have created in mysql. But, i'm not able to do so.

Here is the code of my program. plz help me

```
    Dim row As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
    Dim connection As String
    Dim command As String
    Dim command2 As String
    command2 = "select Company from Stock WHERE Product_Code =('" + TextBox1.Text + "');"
    connection = "Data Source=localhost; Database=Entry; User Id=root; Password=;"
    command = "select Price from Stock WHERE Product_Code =('" + TextBox1.Text + "');"
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection(connection)
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(command)
    Dim data As DataTable
    Dim adp As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim data2 As DataTable
    Dim adp2 As New MySqlDataAdapter
    DataGridView1.Rows.Item(row).Cells(0).Value = TextBox1.Text
    DataGridView1.Rows.Item(row).Cells(2).Value = TextBox2.Text
    Try

        adp = New MySqlDataAdapter(command, connection)
        adp2 = New MySqlDataAdapter(command2, connection)
        data = New DataTable
        data2 = New DataTable
        adp.Fill(data)
        adp2.Fill(data2)
        DataGridView1.Rows.Item(row).Cells(1).Value = data
        DataGridView1.Rows.Item(row).Cells(3).Value = data
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error")
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find examples of how to do this all over SO (stack overflow). But to give you a helping hand, here are the things you need to research:

First, you should parameterize your SQL to prevent injection and readability: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx

Second, you dont add rows to a datagrid, you set the datasource to something that implements IList: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx  Then you add items to your list if you need to.  If you just want to display the rows from your table, you can set the datasource to your datatable (DATA).